# Prevent specific user from seeing a ListView row

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have a ListView that is populated with rows from Parse.com table.

I want that every user will be able to watch and click on every row just one time.

How can I save the Parse.com rows that have been clicked by this user, and prevent him from seeing this row?

**Update #1**

I don't have any examples, because I didn't find anything about it on the web.

To populate the ListView, I used [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-parse-com-listview-images-and-texts-tutorial/) guide.

Comment: could you post some examples of your code or a quick demo-app showing the problem?

Comment: Store clicked data to database and compare it with the list of parse.com then remove matched data from the list of parse.com

Comment: @sanatshukla The problem is that I'm pretty new to Parse.com service and ListViews. Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add user's name to an array on this row, whenever there is a click event.

Add this row to your activity:

```
query.whereNotEqualTo("arrayName", "userName");
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "**How can I save the Parse.com rows that have been clicked by this user, and prevent him from seeing this row?**" ?

Do you mean that we can see a row at the first time, but after we click it, it dispear and we cannot see it anymore?

I think we can add a column into the table indecating the row status, after we click the row, we change the row status and delete it from the listview. Nexttime we initialize the listview by querying data via the row status

Comment: According what you say, this row will be deleted for all of the users. I want to block this row only to the user who clicked it on the ListView.

Comment: No need to delete, I said adding a column to mark the click status, or store the row id in local, I don't know it is rational or not.